# Numpy: not supported between instances of 'method' and 'float

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, statsmodels, state-space

Thanks to everyone in advance for their time!

I am trying to run a TVP-VAR for a panel in the statespace mlemodels in statsmodel. I get an error while trying to fit the model. Not only that, but I cannot really locate the part of the code the error comes from. How could I do that ? I use Spyder as IDE and the only type error is showing is:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'float'

File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 113, in _clip_dep_invoke_with_casting
    return ufunc(*args, out=out, **kwargs)
```

The errors are pumping up when I am trying to run a preliminary estimation of the model

```
preliminary = tvppanelvarmodel.fit(maxiter=1000)
enter code here
```

Why is it so? Is there a way to understand the reason of these and advice on how to set it up.

When I open Numpy _methos.py in order to see the error it reads

```
def _clip_dep_invoke_with_casting(ufunc, *args, out=None, casting=None, **kwargs):
    # normal path
    if casting is not None:
        return ufunc(*args, out=out, casting=casting, **kwargs)

    # try to deal with broken casting rules
    try:
        return ufunc(*args, out=out, **kwargs)
    except _exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError as e:
        # Numpy 1.17.0, 2019-02-24
        warnings.warn(
            "Converting the output of clip from {!r} to {!r} is deprecated. "
            "Pass `casting=\"unsafe\"` explicitly to silence this warning, or "
            "correct the type of the variables.".format(e.from_, e.to),
            DeprecationWarning,
            stacklevel=2
        )
        return ufunc(*args, out=out, casting="unsafe", **kwargs)
```

The full code I am running is:

```
class TVPVAR(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    

   
    def start_params(self):
       
        start_params =  [.1, .1, 100, 100, 100]
        
    
    def __init__(self, y):
        # Create a matrix with [y_t' : y_{t-1}'] for t = 2, ..., T
        augmented = sm.tsa.lagmat(y, 1, trim='both', original='in', use_pandas=True)
        # Separate into y_t and z_t = [1 : y_{t-1}']
      
        p = y.shape[1]
        y_t = augmented.iloc[:, :p]
        z_t = sm.add_constant(augmented.iloc[:, p:])
        nobs = y.shape[0]
        T=y.shape[0]
         
        # Recall that the length of the state vector is p * (p + 1)
        k_states = p * (p + 1)
        super(TVPVAR,self).__init__(y_t, exog=None, k_states=k_states,k_posdef=k_states)
    
        
        self.k_y = p
        self.k_states = p * (p + 1)  
        self.nobs = T  
        self['design'] = np.zeros((self.k_y, self.k_states, 1))  
        
        self['transition'] = np.eye(k_states) # G
        self['selection'] = np.eye(k_states) # R=1
        
     
        
    def update_variances(self, obs_cov, state_cov_diag):
        self['obs_cov'] = obs_cov
        self['state_cov'] = np.diag(state_cov_diag)    # W
        init = initialization.Initialization(self.k_states)
        init.set((0, 2), 'diffuse')
        init.set((2, 4), 'stationary')
        self.ssm.initialize(init)
        
  
   
    def constrain_stationary_multivariate(unconstrained, variance,
                                      transform_variance=False,
                                      prefix=None):
      
        
      unconstrained =np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y * order)
      variance=np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y)
       
      order  = k_y
      
      prefix = find_best_blas_type(
            [unconstrained, variance])
      dtype = prefix_dtype_map[prefix]

      unconstrained = np.asfortranarray(unconstrained, dtype=dtype)
      variance = np.asfortranarray(variance, dtype=dtype)
      # Step 1: convert from arbitrary matrices to those with singular values
      # less than one.
      # sv_constrained = _constrain_sv_less_than_one(unconstrained, order,
      #                                              k_y, prefix)

      sv_constrained = prefix_sv_map[prefix](unconstrained, order, k_y)
      # Step 2: convert matrices from our "partial autocorrelation matrix"
      # space (matrices with singular values less than one) to the space of
      # stationary coefficient matrices
      constrained, variance = prefix_pacf_map[prefix](
        sv_constrained, variance, transform_variance, order, k_y)

      constrained = np.zeros_like(constrained, dtype=dtype)
      variance = np.zeros_like(variance, dtype=dtype)

      return constrained, variance
      
   
    def unconstrain_stationary_multivariate(constrained, error_variance):
       
       constrained= np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y * order)
       error_variance=np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y)
       # Step 1: convert matrices from the space of stationary
    # coefficient matrices to our "partial autocorrelation matrix" space
    # (matrices with singular values less than one)
       partial_autocorrelations = _compute_multivariate_pacf_from_coefficients(
        constrained, error_variance, order, k_y)
       unconstrained = _unconstrain_sv_less_than_one(
        partial_autocorrelations, order, k_y)
       return unconstrained, error_variance
      
     

    def update(self, params, **kwargs):
        params = super().update(params, **kwargs)
        self['transition', 2,2] = params[0]
        self['transition', 3,2] = params[1]
        self['state_cov'] = np.diag([params[2]**2, params[3]**2, params[4]**2])  # W
    
    @property
    def state_names(self):
        state_names = np.empty((self.k_y, self.k_y + 1), dtype=object)
        for i in range(self.k_y):
            endog_name = self.y__names[i]
            state_names[i] = (
                ['intercept.%s' % y_name] +
                ['L1.%s->%s' % (other_name, y_name) for other_name in self.y_names])
        return state_names.ravel().tolist()
    
    
tvppanelvarmodel = TVPVAR(y)
index=year

preliminary = tvppanelvarmodel.fit(maxiter=1000)



res = tvppanelvarmodel.fit(preliminary.params, method='nm', disp=0, maxiter=1000) 
print(res.summary())

    
    # Impluse Response 
    ax = res.impulse_responses(10, orthogonalized=True, impulse=[1, 0]).plot(figsize=(13,3))
    ax.set(xlabel='t', title='Responses to a shock to `xxxx`');
```

I have seen the previous answer by Chad Fulton(@cfulton) on [the initial conditions for statespace mlemodel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514668/initial-conditions-for-statespace-mlemodel-in-statsmodel?_gl=1*6lzfwl*_ga*MTM5MTM1ODc2My4xNjMxOTkwMDQz*_ga_WCZ03SZFCQ*MTY2MzMzNzU2NS41LjEuMTY2MzMzOTQxOS4wLjAuMA..), my code looks inline

Comment: where in your code is this error coming from? you're trying to compare a method to a float, that doesn't work

Comment: Copying and pasting all of your code doesn't help us narrow down your issue. Could you reduce it to a minimal example I could copy and paste into my own editor?

Comment: Show the full error message, with traceback.  We can't deduce where the error occurs (especially since '>=' isn't in the code you show).  Most likely you are using 'arg.foo' when you should be using 'arg.foo()` - missing function/method call ().

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions. You should have edited your original question if you just wanted to add tags. At this point, please delete your original question and then [edit] this post to include all relevant information that's been requested.  Don't use comments to provide information, post it in the main body of your post.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post. Sorry for any inconvenience caused. I am a new guy on the forums!

Comment: Instead of posting code from internal numpy modules and functions, you should post the full error output (that starts with "Traceback (most recent call first)"), as requested above. And for debugging help, as mentioned above, it is best to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want more tips.